# Mongo db docker authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

First of all this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow and English is not my native language. Sorry in advence if there are any mistakes. I'm creating a rest-api with language go and using docker image of mongodb as my database. My docker-compose.yaml file is like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
  api:
    build : .
    container_name: restapi
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I set my variables as an .env file. When I run `docker compose up -d --build` command it creates 2 containers which named mongo and restapi respectively. But when i try to access my database using command `docker exec -it mongo mongosh` and `use admin` and then `show collections` it gives me this error:

> > "MongoServerError: not authorized on admin to execute command {
> > > listCollections: 1, filter: {}, cursor: {}, nameOnly: true,
> > > authorizedCollections: false, lsid: { id:
> > > UUID("d02d6b74-0f09-4cee-8c08-b2842b1dc6b2") }, $db: "admin",
> > > $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }"

After that i tried `use admin` and `db.auth('myusername','mypassword')` Even though my username and password are correct it's just says:
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.

I really tried nearly everything and now i'm stuck. Every help will be appreciated

Comment: Try using `db` as the hostname for the mongo uri in api container. `localhost` resolves to the container running `api`, not to the localhost on which you're running the containers.

Comment: Same outcome i'm afraid.

Comment: Use of admin db is restricted to system admins. Use a different db to store your data.

Comment: Well i'm trying to use another db to store my data but i can't even use `show collections` or even `show dbs`. Or `db.createCollection` to create a collection. I am simply not authorized to do so.

Comment: After using the docker exec command, use `mongo admin -u uname -p 'password'`. It solved my issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470